# jquery animation help

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, dom-manipulation

I am trying to build the following,

[image: Animated Backgroup Dependent On Page]

Basically what should happen is the dark green bar underneath the white text should grow and shrink dependent on which link is active, so for example at the moment, THE JOBWALL link is active so the green bar spans the width of that link. How can I achive this affect, is it possible to animate the backgroud-image that would create the green bar so that when the page loads the bar animates from left-right until it rest under the active page?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general idea that might work for you:

1. Create a div with id whitebar. Style
   it to have correct height and width,
   and set the bg color.
2. Embed another div in whitebar with
   id green bar. Make it as wide as
   your page titles. Set the bg color
   to green.
3. Now animate the green bar using
   standard jquery animation techniques

If the titles are not of equal widths you might need to resize the greenbar at the beginning  or end of animation.

EDIT: Here is a [rough sketch](http://jsfiddle.net/h8PBS/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with jQuery. Here's how.

First make an element for each menu item that will be the green bar. You'll have to position it correctly with CSS. Set the background color of this element to your dark green color, and the width to zero (so that it is not visible by default).

Then, provide a callback to the menu items' onmouseover event:

```
 <div class="menu-item" onmouseover="menuRollover(this)" >...</div>
```

In the callback

```
function menuRollover(el){
    $(el).find(".green-bar").animate({'width':60}, 200)
```

This will animate the bar's width to 60px, in a period of 200 ms.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why not take full advantage and wire up the hover() method instead?

Comment: Yes, $('.menu-item').hover(callback) will be easier, especially if the HTML for the menu items is not being dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this one before, and ran across the question a while ago, got curious, and went to try it out myself on jsfiddle. Here is what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/robx/dXZxN/4/ using several different colors to animate with, but you can easily adjust to your needs.